# Running Script in CMD Works but when ran using Process.Start() in C# python script fails

Tags: c#, python, regex, process

I have a python script, **changeDates.py**, that successfully runs outside of a C# program started in the cmd by the command:

`python changeDates.py path/to/folder numberOfMonths numberOfWeeks testSetsToCheck`

These arguments are all strings. the numberOfMonths and numberOfWeeks is passed to the python script as a string then converted inside the script to an int.

But if i were to run the same command using:

```
private void run_CMD(string cmd, string args, bool messageBox)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cmd);
                Console.WriteLine(args);
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                start.FileName = cmd;
                start.Arguments = args;
                start.UseShellExecute = false;
                start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.Write(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while trying to check package dates: \n" + ex);
                Logger.Write(Logger.Level.ERROR, "Error while trying to check package dates: \n" + ex);
            }
        }
```

The script starts and outputs the following error:

```
 C:\Users\bblashko\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automation_Fr
amework\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\scripts\changeDates.py C:\Users\bblashk
o\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\Athena_Te
st_Automation_Framework\Test_Cases 6 1 00100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bblashko\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automa
tion_Framework\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\scripts\changeDates.py", line 51
0, in <module>
    allFiles = checkContent(content, subDir, int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]))

  File "C:\Users\bblashko\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automa
tion_Framework\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\scripts\changeDates.py", line 47
, in checkContent
    checkXLSX(f, subDir, numberOfMonths, numberOfWeeks)
  File "C:\Users\bblashko\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automa
tion_Framework\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\scripts\changeDates.py", line 85
, in checkXLSX
    changeDate = checkXLSXDates(salesStartDate, pubDate, type, todaysDate, check
Date)
  File "C:\Users\bblashko\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\Athena_Test_Automa
tion_Framework\Athena_Test_Automation_Framework\scripts\changeDates.py", line 15
7, in checkXLSXDates
    if(re.search("(\w\w)/(\w\w)/(\w\w\w\w)", salesStartDate) and re.search("(\w\
w)/(\w\w)/(\w\w\w\w)", pubDate)):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 166, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Why would the regex in the python suddenly result in an error? 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Bad arguments? Maybe you quote the wrong thing -- in Windows quotes are special, special things. Different permissions? In VS you probably have administrative access, while outside you most likely don't. I mean we're just guessing here, need more info!

Comment: I don't know how I could get more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string) argument that you have passed to your `re.search` function is a python module and when you execute your python code in that way the variable `string` doesn't assigned correctly! So, first of all, don't use python key words and built-in names as your variable names and, to get rid of this situation, you need to check the way that you assigned the `string` within your code!

Comment: I don't see how it could be an issue with the python code. since I was able to run the python script successfully in the cmd and through java. Ill check it though.

Comment: @user2853442 i said that when you execute your code with c# the `string` couldn't been assigned correctly! did you pass any argument to your script with c#?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. I will edit my question with the arguments.

Comment: I did use arguments all of which were passed as a string to the python script.

Comment: @user2853442 im not familiar with c#, you need to check the way that you pass `numberOfMonths numberOfWeeks testSetsToCheck` to your python script!